# Python - Combine files/Merge files

Tags: python, file, merge, line

Hoping you can help. I hold 2 .txt files. examples below

- > **.txt1**
- 99   1/1/2013 05:10  london (uk/england) gb  oval    1800    2/4/2013
- 70   1/10/1971 21:00 preston (uk/england)    gb  disk    180 12/19/2003
- 6    1/10/1998 18:00 london (uk/england) gb  circle  240 9/29/2004
- 84   1/10/2002 17:25 nottingham (uk/england) gb  circle  3   1/29/2002

**.txt2**

- 6    "djfdjf"
- 84   "gfgrtret"
- 99   "hytyteghej"
- 70   "yjtytyuytjyj"

**output needed**

- 99   1/1/2013 05:10  london (uk/england) gb  oval    1800    2/4/2013
  hytyteghej
- 70   1/10/1971 21:00 preston (uk/england)    gb  disk    180 12/19/2003
  yjtytyuytjyj
- 6    1/10/1998 18:00 london (uk/england) gb  circle  240 9/29/2004  djfdjf
- 84   1/10/2002 17:25 nottingham (uk/england) gb  circle  3   1/29/2002
  gfgrtret

As you can see, they are not sorted in numerical order. i have been advised however that they can be 'defined' and .txt2 can be added to the end of each line in .txt2.

Can anyone assist with the code i would require to do this?

**ignore the bullet points**

i have code that works already for what i require, however this seems out of my zone currently.

Comment: 1. Load both. 2. Convert second file to dictionary. 3. Append values from dictionary to first file by key (first element in line).

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough for you?
I used pandas for simplicity, but you could avoid it.
I changed the order of the rows, but there must be an easy way to avoid it in case that's a problem.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('text1.txt', sep=" ", index_col=0, header=None)
data2 = pd.read_csv('text2.txt', sep=" ", index_col=0, header=None)

result = pd.concat([data1, data2], axis=1, sort=True)

result.to_csv(r'out.txt', header=None,  sep=' ', mode='a')
```

They are sorted by index

Comment: thanks for the answers. i try to avoid importing panda and numpy usually. i can confirm this doesnt work without numpy (as per the exception)